# Get Result From JSON Output

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

There is an api $url that produces result in the following format:

```
{"status":true,"message":"Good morning","data":{"first_name":"Peter","last_name":"Rick","mobile":"09887","PIN":"1234"}}
```

I've tried file_get_contents as follows but not getting desired results.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$cont=json_decode($contents,true);
$cont = array($contents);
$message = $cont->message;
```

How do I get out the values of the variables status,message,first_name,last_name,mobile,PIN  using file_get_contents

Comment: just remove third line of code

Comment: And the true from json_decode

Comment: Yep $contents will already be an array after the `json_decode()`

Comment: Since your passing `true` as your second argument to json_encode(), everything will be arrays which makes `$cont->message` invalid. Just remove the `$cont = array($contents);` and just do: `$message = $contents['message']`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How do i get the firs_name value for instance, since it is under "data"

Comment: `$contents` is just a multidimensional array, so use it as such. Do a `var_dump($contents)` and you'll see what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$contents = '{"status":true,"message":"Good morning","data":{"first_name":"Peter","last_name":"Rick","mobile":"09887","PIN":"1234"}}';
$cont=json_decode($contents);
$message = $cont->message;


echo $cont->data->first_name;
echo '<br />';
echo $cont->data->last_name;
echo '<br />';
echo $cont->data->mobile;
echo '<br />';
echo $cont->data->PIN;
```

The way you tried to access your message variable applies to objects so you have to remove the `true` option from json decode so you create an object and not an array.

Also `json_decode` creates an array or an object (based on option TRUE , FALSE) so your third line is unnecessary 
Further more i provide you help on how to echo the values you need.

Output is:

```
Peter
Rick
09887
1234
```